# Можно ли как-нибудь изменить количество выводящихся элементов пагинации SwiperJS

Tags: javascript, swiper

Можно ли как-нибудь изменить количество выводящихся элементов пагинации SwiperJS. Желательно чтобы выводилось 3 года, а когда листаешь появлялись новые, а старые пропадали

```js
var menu = ['1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994']
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // If we need pagination
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (menu[index]) + '</span>';
        },
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  })
```

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.swiper-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    margin: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    padding: 5px 10px!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
    width: auto!important;
    height: 30px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    color:#000!important;
    opacity: 1!important;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)!important;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    color:#fff!important;
    background: #007aff!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" >Content</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так хотели?
Думаю если посмотреть [демки](https://swiperjs.com/demos), то можно найти и более подходящее

```js
var menu = ['1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994']
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    // If we need pagination
    slidesPerView: 3,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (menu[index]) + '</span>';
        },
    },

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  })
```

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.swiper-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    margin: 0;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
    padding: 5px 10px!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
    width: auto!important;
    height: 30px!important;
    text-align: center!important;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    font-size: 12px!important;
    color:#000!important;
    opacity: 1!important;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2)!important;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
    color:#fff!important;
    background: #007aff!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" >Content</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">Content</div>
    </div>
    <!-- If we need pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    
    <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: я может неправильно высказал что я хочу получить. http://www.omskcarbongroup.com/company/ вот тут ниже есть слайдер. Хочу чтобы пагинация была примерно как там(с годами где история компании) .

Comment: пробовал         dynamicBullets: true,
        dynamicMainBullets: 2, но не работает

Comment: @Вадим да сам смотрю

Answer (score 0):

https://moredez.ru/slider-swiper-api-20181018

вот это параметр кажется `slidesPerView`